# Substituting Ruby strings

Tags: ruby, string-substitution

So if this `"%05d" % 123` returns `#=> "00123"`, I would expect `"%05d" % 0123` to return `#=> "00123"` as well, but instead it returns `#=> "00083"`.  Why is this so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Numbers starting with 0 are interpreted as octal, just like numbers starting with 0x are interpreted as hexadecimal. 83 is represented as 123 in octal.

```
irb(main):001:0> 0123
=> 83
irb(main):002:0> 1*8**2 + 2*8**1 + 3*8**0
=> 83
irb(main):003:0> "%05d" % 0x7b
=> "00123"
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I ended up using this instead: 

    `value = "0123" 
    value = value.rjust(5, '0')`